# I have received the following email from UK Visas and Immigration. Please help me out!

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

I have submitted 4 applications on 5th april at VAC,Lahore, Pakistan and received this email for all 4 of us...

> Dear Customer,
>
> Your UK visa application has been issued.
>
> PLEASE DO NOT GO TO THE VISA APPLICATION CENTRE BEFORE THEY CONTACT
>   YOU.
>
> You will be contacted by the Visa Application Centre when your
>   documents are ready for collection, or have been dispatched via
>   courier where this is relevant.
>
> You are reminded that you should avoid making travel plans until you
>   have collected your passport, as the outcome of your visa application
>   is not final until you receive your passport.
>
> Please ensure you check the details on your visa when collecting your
>   passport. If you need to contact us you can do so via our
>   International Enquiry Service at https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-outside-uk
>
> Kind regards,
>
> UK Visas and Immigration British Embassy Abu Dhabi https://www.gov.uk/ukvi

Please help me out what decision should I expect?

Answer (score 2):

We can’t tell - this is just the advice to say the decision has been made, it indicates nothing, neither approval or refusal. No-one will be able to tell you the decision, you can only find out when you get your documents back.

Comment: I thought that visas are issued because of the word issued and secondly they have mentioned to check details on visa!  That's why i asked :)

Comment: @qasimcool Unfortunately it’s bad use of the word ‘issued’ - it should read ‘decided’, IMHO as a native English speaker

Comment: Or maybe "the decision on your application has been issued".